# Node bcrypt returning always false result

Tags: node.js, routes, deployment, backend, webcrypto-api

this is my hash functions

```
userSchema.pre('save', async function(next) {
    try {
        if (this.isModified('password')) {
            const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 10);
            this.password = hashedPassword;
        }
        next();
    } catch (error) {
        next(error);
    }
});

userSchema.methods.comparePassword = async function(trimmedCandidatePassword, storedHashedPassword) {
    try {
      const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(trimmedCandidatePassword, storedHashedPassword);
      console.log("bcrypt.compare result:", isMatch); // View the direct bcrypt result
      return isMatch; 
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error(error);
    }
  };
```

and this is the login route which handles the route of login logic

```
router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { username, password,role } = req.body;
        const user = await User.findOne({ username });

        // Checking is the username exists
        if (!user) {
            return res.status(401).json({ message: "User doesnt exist" });
        }
        console.log("Entered Password:", password); 
        console.log("Stored Hashed Password:", user.password);

        const storedHashedPassword = user.password.trim();
        const enteredPassword = password.trim();
        // Checking password
        const isPassWordValid = await user.comparePassword(enteredPassword,storedHashedPassword);
        console.log(isPassWordValid)

        if (!isPassWordValid) {
            return res.status(401).json({ message: "Incorrect Password" });
        }
        if(role!==user.role){
            return res.status(401).json({ message: "you are not assigned for this role" });
        }
        const token = jwt.sign({ 
            userId: user._id, 
            role: user.role  // Add the user's role to the token
        }, process.env.SECRET_KEY);
        res.status(200).json({ token });
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: "Authentication Failed x2", error: error.message })
    }
});
```

i have {
"username":"sarthak@123",
"password":"sarthak123",
"role":"Doctor"
}
in my body of route i checked the hash stored in database and still getting always false

Comment: Post the code where you create/sign-up the user please, it's likely you are hashing twice which is quite common. Also why are you using `trim()` on the `user.password`? You don't need to pass in a `storedHashedPassword` value because the value will be available in the instance method using `this.password`.